# Why does stacking CNN wreck reproducibility (even with seed & CPU)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, random, keras, reproducible-research

**REPRODUCIBLE**:

```py
ipt = Input(batch_shape=batch_shape)
x   = Conv2D(6, (8, 8), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(ipt)
x   = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(x)
```

**NOT REPRODUCIBLE**:

```py
ipt = Input(batch_shape=batch_shape)
x   = Conv2D(6, (8, 8), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(ipt)
x   = Conv2D(6, (8, 8), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(x)
x   = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(x)
```

---

The difference amplifies substantially when using a larger model, and actual data instead of random noise - up to **30% difference in accuracy** (relative) **within a single small epoch**. Environment setup, considered sources, and full minimal reproducible example below. [Relevant Git](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33942)

What is the problem, and how to fix it?

---

**POSSIBLE SOURCES**: (**[x]** = ruled out)

- **[x]** TF2 vs. TF1; Keras 2.3.0+ vs. Keras 2.2.5 (tested both)
- **[x]** Random seeds (`numpy`, `tf`, `random`, `PYTHONHASHSEED`)
- **[x]** Data values / shuffling (same values, no shuffling)
- **[x]** Weight initializations (same values)
- **[x]** GPU usage (used CPU)
- **[x]** CPU multithreading (used single thread; also see below's 'further')
- **[x]** Numeric imprecision (used float64; further, extent of discrepancy too large for num. impr.)
- **[x]** Bad CUDA install (all [official guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.0/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html) tests passed, TF detects GPU & CUDA)

---

**ENVIRONMENT**:

- CUDA 10.0.130, cuDNN 7.6.0, Windows 10, GTX 1070
- Python 3.7.4, Spyder 3.3.6, Anaconda 3.0 2019.10
- Anaconda Powershell Prompt terminal to set `PYTHONHASHSEED` and start Spyder

---

**OBSERVATIONS**:

- `float64` vs. `float32` - no noticeable difference
- CPU vs. GPU - no noticeable difference
- Non-reproducible also for `Conv1D`
- Reproducible for `Dense` replacing `Conv`; other layers not tested
- For a [larger model](https://pastebin.com/VSV7jv7x), which is still 'small', loss variance is substantial within a single epoch:

```py
one_epoch_loss = [1.6814, 1.6018, 1.6577, 1.6789, 1.6878, 1.7022, 1.6689]
one_epoch_acc  = [0.2630, 0.3213, 0.2991, 0.3185, 0.2583, 0.2463, 0.2815]
```

---

**CODE**:

```py
batch_shape = (32, 64, 64, 3)
num_samples = 1152

ipt = Input(batch_shape=batch_shape)
x   = Conv2D(6, (8, 8), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(ipt)
x   = Conv2D(6, (8, 8), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(x)
x   = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

X = np.random.randn(num_samples, *batch_shape[1:])
y = np.random.randint(0, 6, (num_samples, 1))

reset_seeds()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, shuffle=False)
```

---

**Imports / setup**:

```py
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
import random
random.seed(2)

import tensorflow as tf
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
      intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
      inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf) # single-threading; TF1-only

def reset_seeds():
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(2)
    if tf.__version__[0] == '2':
        tf.random.set_seed(3)
    else:
        tf.set_random_seed(3)
    print("RANDOM SEEDS RESET")
reset_seeds()

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K

K.set_floatx('float64')
```