# Differences between the Tensorflow Class BinaryCrossentropy and the Function binary_crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am incredibly confused as to the differences between the Tensorflow Class `BinaryCrossentropy` and the Function `binary_crossentropy`.  The page where I see both on the documentation is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses).  The pages for the [Class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) and the [Function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/binary_crossentropy) look nearly identical so if someone could explain it in a way that makes sense that would be fantastic.

Furthermore (but not really the main issue here) is when I pass the Function into my `model.compile()` it does not give me any errors, and what is even *more* confusing to me is that I can seemingly pass anything into `model.compile()` and running the line won't give any errors. Something like this:

`model.compile(loss='gibberish')` gives absolutely no errors, despite the `gibberish` loss function is defined nowhere. The documentation looks near identical so if someone could explain it in a way that makes sense that would be fantastic.

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: let me reach you for 2nd item  where you have put `model.compile(loss='gibberish')` , pls note that you will get the error when you try to fit the model `model.fit(x_train,y_train)` you will see that error will be thrown then.

Comment: also pls refer [binarycrossentropy-and-binary-crossentropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612914/difference-about-binarycrossentropy-and-binary-crossentropy-in-tf-keras-loss)